# Avoid unexpected match

Tags: regex

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
<text>bla bla BLU bla bla</text>
<text>bla bla bla bla bla</text>
<text>bla BLU bla bla bla</text>
<text>bla ble bla bla bla</text>
```

I'm looking for a way to get each `<text>` entry with `BLU` inside it. I tried using this Regular Expression:

```
/<text>[\s\S]*?BLU[\s\S]*?<\/text>/g
```

I get 2 matches, as expected, but the second match will be:

```
<text>bla bla bla bla bla</text>
<text>bla BLU bla bla bla</text>
```

**How can I avoid this kind of match and only get this result as second match:**

```
<text>bla BLU bla bla bla</text>
```

Comment: Offering half your total points for something so simple ? `<text>[^<]*BLU[^<]*</text>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a floor in your logic.

The reason this is happening is because even though the `[\s\S]*` is lazy, it will carry on until it finds `BLU`. This means it will find the opening `<text>` tag, and then carry on past the closing one, to the next line until it finds `BLU`.

You can try the following RegEx:

```
<text>(?:(?!<\/text>)[\s\S])*?BLU[\s\S]*?<\/text>
```

The bit I changed was `[\s\S]*?`, to `(?:(?!<\/text>)[\s\S])*?`.

`[\s\S]` is enclosed inside a non-capturing group. At the start of the group, there is a **Negative Lookahead** that will fail if it finds a closing `</text>`.

This way the `[\s\S]*?` will never match a closing `</text>`, and therefore it fixes your problem.

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/kT6hU8/1)</kbd>

[image: Demo]

---

Note that if there are no newlines between the opening and closing `<text>` tags, you can use the following RegEx:

```
<text>.*?BLU.*?<\/text>
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/gW6eW3/1)</kbd>

Comment: You could also unroll the tempered greedy token - your `<text>(?:(?!<\/text>)[\s\S])*?BLU[\s\S]*?<\/text>` is rather inefficient.